# Не работает border-radius

Tags: css, html5

Проблема заключается в том, что после добавления градиента для блока .logo перестал работать border-radius. Выручайте)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:300,400,500,700');
a.logo {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 6px 20px 5px;
  margin-top: 0.65em;
  border: 0.115em solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* border */
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(179, 0, 255, 0.9556197478991597) 30%, rgba(42, 198, 231, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(179, 0, 255, 0.9556197478991597) 30%, rgba(42, 198, 231, 1) 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(179, 0, 255, 0.9556197478991597) 30%, rgba(42, 198, 231, 1) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* text */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(179, 0, 255, 0.9556197478991597) 30%, rgba(42, 198, 231, 1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a class="logo">ЛОГОТИП</a>
```

Comment: `border-image` + `border-radius` = не совместимы!

Comment: Делаете не border, а сплошную заливку из градиента. А внутри еще один блок с текстом и белым фоном

Answer (score 0):

Набросал [пример](https://codepen.io/paveldemyanenko/pen/BVzjVY) с фоном и свойством border-radius. Нужно было заменить `-webkit-background-clip: text;` на `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;`
и убрать прозрачность для текста. Если возникнут дополнительные вопросы, то с радость отвечу :)

Comment: Ты просто залил блок...
А мне нужно чтоб border был

Comment: Простите, если из вашего описания я не понял, что именно вы хотите сделать. Как написал человек выше вам необходим дополнительный контейнер, чтобы верстка приняла вид, соответствующий вашему дизайну :)